# How to check in another table if an agency is in a specific region

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, worksheet-function, vlookup

There are many travel agencies each with a code of three characters in a column. I want to know if the travel agency is in Atlantic Canada. I can get a list of all the codes corresponding to travel agencies in Atlantic Canada from a database and put them in a single column in another worksheet in the same Excel file, but I'm not sure of the exact syntax for writing the IF ...LOOKUP or if there is a better Excel formula/technique.

If the codes are in D2:D68 in this example, I want column E (E2:E68) to look up if the value in column D corresponds to one of the lengthy list of codes. Column E would then display yes/no or true/false or something similar.

I've been looking at various tutorials. I don't want to actually look up anything, I just want yes/no or true/false that the three-character code is one of, or not one of, the many Atlantic Canada codes.

Suggestions?

Comment: Try with LOOKUP function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your reference list in in ColumnA of Sheet 2, try `=VLOOKUP(D2,Sheet2!A:A,1,FALSE)` in `E2` copied down as required. This could be adapted to show TRUE/FALSE but for identification purposes a code repeat seems adequate. FALSE is to accept a match only when exact (TRUE would allow approximate matches - ie similar but not correct). Ones that do not match will display`#NAME?`

Edit

For T/F results
 `=IFERROR(IF(MATCH(D1,'Atlantic Canada Codes'!A:A,0)>0,"TRUE","FALSE"),"FALSE")`
should work (though something much less inelegant seems possible!)

*Edit re apparent inconsistency in formulae results as mentioned in a comment*

- `=TRIM()` (worksheet) and `Trim` (VBA) behave differently.
- `=MATCH` and `=V / H LOOKUP()` may behave differently according to whether exact or otherwise.
- A space character may be ‘normal’ (7-bit ASCII code 32) or non-breaking (&nbsp code 160).

Rather than cover all these combinations, a simplified (so far from complete) explanation is that where ‘extra’ spaces are a problem, usually trailing ones, apply `=TRIM()` to **both** the data to be looked up (ie the key) and to at least that part of the array (the keys) which relate to the required results.

It is possible that the apparent inconsistency mentioned in a comment arose because `something+space` was not matching to `something` and that in removing `+space` from `something+space` the same was applied to `somethingelse+space`. Hence where before =TRIM() `somethingesle+space` was matching with `somethingelse+space` after `somethingelse` was no longer matching with `somethingelse+space`.

That is the problem was switched from 'surplus' spaces in one list to 'surplus' spaces in the other. Either have these spaces in neither, or if you must, in both.

[Ref:](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/trim-function-HP010062581.aspx)

Comment: I modified your suggestion to =VLOOKUP(D2,'Atlantic Canada Codes'!A:A,1,FALSE) and it returned #N/A for a code not in the list, let me try one that should be in the list.  When I test it on a valid code it returns the value of the code, I need to convert it to true false or yes/no. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Changing it along the lines of the suggestion above =NOT(ISERR(VLOOKUP(D67,'Atlantic Canada Codes'!A:A,1,FALSE))) always returns TRUE, ISERR might be the issue as VLOOKUP will return an error...

Comment: Your last suggestion is working, I also discovered that some of the data has preceeding blank space, which won't MATCH, one more thing to fix/look out for. Thanks again.

Comment: Will MATCH work on codes that start with numbers and letters. I added the trim, and tried to manually remove proceeding whitespace, but now the formula is not matching code 263 which is in Atlantic Canada but does match E01 which is also in Atlantic Canada. Basically thre are 3 Atlantic Canada Bookings and this code only finds one, E01.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Taking out the TRIM() makes it match 263. I wish one formula would work for all data.

Answer (score 1):

Given your current spreadsheet, you could test the error condition of a VLOOKUP.

```
=NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A5,D:D,1,0)))
```

If there's a convenient way to concatenate the column of values into a single cell of comma-separated values, then you can do a FIND against a single cell.  There may be performance advantages (only significant if your spreadsheet is large enough that you sometimes wait for it to recalculate).

```
=NOT(ISERROR(FIND(A5,D2,1,0)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I tried the first one modified to: =NOT(ISERR(VLOOKUP(D2,'Atlantic Canada Codes'!A41:A76,1,0))) and it returned true for D2, which has a value of E85 and returns TRUE, unfortunantly E85 isn't in the Atlantic Canada Codes column as far as I can see. I can remove the NOT or something, I'm off to play some more.

Comment: Alas removing the NOT just makes the formula always return TRUE, now to make sure real data actually contains a sale from Atlantic Canada.

Comment: I also fixed it to $A$2:$A$76 and it never varies it is either always TRUE or always FALSE depending on the NOT, even if I type in an Atlantic Canada agent code.

Comment: My bad... change ISERR to ISERROR.  I'll fix it in the answer as well.

Comment: For the VLOOKUP, ISNA(...) would be more precise than ISERROR(...), although it ultimately accomplishes the same thing.

Comment: Thanks I'm using the solution above, but yours may well work. I had some white space issues so I had to start trimming things and various managers came up with other summaries they wanted to see, so certain core techniques around MATCH, VLOOKUP, and SUMIFS were needed.

Comment: People will learn from both and use whatever actually helps them.